# jQuery: Adding a div's property and value to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, properties

I have a div which style properties are automatically given by [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com) depending on the size of the browser:

```
<div id="container" class="transitions-enabled clearfix masonry"
 style="position:relative; height: 1686px; width: 1600px; visibility: visible;">
```

Is there a way to add the `height` property and value to another div?

This is how the result would preferably look like:

```
<div class="footer" style="width: 1600px"></div>
```

Comment: There is the jquery [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) and the [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) . I think these could be of use if i am understanding your question. I am not sure how Masonry works so this might not be applicable. Why do you add the style tag if you have an associated class for the div?

Comment: Well, thought that was the easiest way :P

Comment: Cool. Sorry i just never do that, but that's all coding style. It can be helpful though in a lot of circumstances, especially if you are working mainly in the html document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite easily using jQuery:

Width:

```
$('.footer').width($('#container').width());
```

[**jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/NJHNQ/1/)

Or height:

```
$('.footer').height($('#container').height());
```

[**jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/NJHNQ/)